# How to write serverside code in csHTML

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I want to write some server side code to display the data stored in the View Data of the page in the csHtml page. I have done some research but couldn't find a solution. Output of the code is [image]

```
  @(Html.Kendo().TabStrip()
                    .Name("Logins")
                    .SelectedIndex(0)
                    .Animation(animation => animation.Open(open => open.Fade(FadeDirection.In)))
                    .Items(items =>
                    {


                        items.Add().Text("Contact Information").Content(
                            "<div class='employee-details'>" +
                                "<ul>" +
                                "<%>for(int i=0;i<8;i++)"+
                        "{<%>"+
                                    "<li><label>LoginID:</label>"+viewDataServer[i].LoginID.ToString()+"</li>" +
                                    "<li><label>ServerID:</label>" + viewDataServer[i].ServerID.ToString() + "</li>" +
                                    "<li><label>UserID:</label>" + viewDataServer[i].UserID.ToString() + "</li>" +
                                    "<li><label>Password:</label>" + viewDataServer[i].passwd.ToString() + "</li>" +
                                "<%>}<%>"+
                                "</ul>" +
                            "</div>"

                          );      

                    })
                .ToClientTemplate())
```

Comment: Why have you included the loop there?  You're not using i anywhere?

Comment: sorry i have updated it.

Comment: Are you using MVC 2 or later? Which view engine are you using? You seem to be mixing the Web Forms engine syntax with the angle brackets and percent signs and Razor syntax with the "at" symbol. I assume from the fact that your Kendo tabstrip renders using the @ symbol, and that your page file extension is cshtml, that you are using ASP.NET MVC 3 or later and the Razor view engine. As far as I know the angle brackets and percent symbols will only render in ".aspx" pages. You may have an outdated tutorial or be using the wrong Kendo UI demo.

Comment: Actually i donot know what to use <%> or  @ but i had tired both of them and the could get the required result. it is in the tabstrip

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you are looking at the wrong view engine page on the [Telerik tabstrip demo site](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/tabstrip/index) - instead of "index.aspx" you need to look at "index.cshtml" if you are using the Razor view engine.

I think that the correct syntax in your case would be-

```
@(Html.Kendo().TabStrip()
                    .Name("Logins")
                    .SelectedIndex(0)
                    .Animation(animation => animation.Open(open => open.Fade(FadeDirection.In)))
                    .Items(items =>
                    {
                        items.Add().Text("Contact Information").Content(@<div class='employee-details'>
                                <ul>
                                @for(var i=0; i<8; i++)
                                {
                                    <li><label>LoginID:</label>@viewDataServer[i].LoginID.ToString()</li>
                                    <li><label>ServerID:</label>@viewDataServer[i].ServerID.ToString()</li>
                                    <li><label>UserID:</label>@viewDataServer[i].UserID.ToString()</li>
                                    <li><label>Password:</label>@viewDataServer[i].passwd.ToString()</li>
                                }
                                </ul>
                            </div>);
                    })
                .ToClientTemplate())
```

I would however **strongly** encourage you not to use ViewData to page data from your controller to the view in this way. This is exactly the purpose of a view model, which would be strongly typed. If for some reason using a view model is not practical, I would suggest you at least consider ViewBag - which is a dynamic type - meaning that you could pass an IEnumerable (or List) of a strongly typed class, perhaps your Contact object, and simply enumerate through them using something like-

```
@foreach (var contact in ViewBag.Contacts) { ... }
```

The ideal would absolutely be to set the model to a List or IEnunerable like-

```
@model IEnumerable<Contact>
```

And then enumerate in your View as follows-

```
@foreach (var contact in Model) { ... }
```

Comment: The blog post at http://weblogs.asp.net/hajan/viewbag-dynamic-in-asp-net-mvc-3-rc-2 may be helpful for learning more about ViewBag - but I'd still strongly encourage you to use a view model rather than either ViewData or ViewBag.